# Detect warning in MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, dlib, suppress-warnings

Recently, we discovered that one of our external libraries (DLib) is suppressing warnings at a global level. Writing the following code gives us a warning:

```
[[deprecated]] int findDeprecated() { return 42; }
int test = findDeprecated();
```

Including a dlib header suppresses the warning:

```
#include <dlib/matrix.h>
[[deprecated]] int findDeprecated() { return 42; }
int test = findDeprecated();
```

Having to trigger all of these warnings in order to vet our external libraries is very cumbersome and not easy to integrate in our codebase.
Hence we would like to create a new test that conceptually looks like:

```
#include <dlib>
#include <boost>

static_assert(getWarningLevel(4996) == 4, "Deprecated Warning Was suppressed");
```

However, from searching around, we can't find a way to request the warning level as search engines always tell us how to enable the warning.
Does a way exist in order to retrieve the warning level?

Some restrictions to the answer:

- We are only interested in Visual Studio 2017 (or above)
- Extra points: Have a solution for clang-cl as well

Comment: Do not include those headers directly. Include one of your own headers, that includes the library header, then reenables all the warnings. Write a unit test that scans the source and flags any translation unit that includes the library header directly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - It's hard to scan a TU.  You'd be better scanning the source and header files - **except** the wrapping header.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I rather detect it and get the libraries fixed instead, without having to do a manual inspection of all headers. For dlib, it's still possible, for boost (with a lot of preprocessor magic) I don't want to do that

Comment: As far as writing that test goes; seems like a perfect fit for a custom [Clang-Tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) check :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl For Clang -> Yes, really good idea, for MSVC -> different preprocessor paths and as result not usable

Answer (score 3):

You can save and restore your warning level(s) with:

```
#pragma warning(push) // Save current warning state
#include <offendingheaderfile.h>
#pragma warning(pop)  // Restore saved warning state
```

Comment: You can indeed do this, at all 10.000 headers that include the libraries. Ain't really scalable